# How to use lzma2 in python code?

Tags: python, compression, 7zip, lzma

I know there is a module called pylzma. But it only support lzma, not lzma2.

My current solution is using `subprocess.call()` to call 7z program.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backports.lzma](https://github.com/peterjc/backports.lzma), see for more info: [Python 2.7: Compressing data with the XZ format using the "lzma" module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370068/python-2-7-compressing-data-with-the-xz-format-using-the-lzma-module)

Then it's simply a matter of doing e.g.:

```
from backports import lzma

with open('hello.xz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(lzma.compress(b'hello', format=lzma.FORMAT_XZ))
```

Or simpler (XZ format is default):

```
with lzma.open('hello.xz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'hello')
```

See http://docs.python.org/dev/library/lzma.html for usage details.